# What's the purpose of DTD-related Entity and EntityReference DOM Node Types?

Tags: html, xml, dom, dtd, w3c

I'm confused about how the various DOM node types fit in with DTDs.

Okay, so the W3C DOM specification categorizes XML/HTML components into nodes (which most of us are familiar with through Javascript programming or XML parsing.)

The [**nodes types**](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) are:

```
Document
DocumentFragment
DocumentType
EntityReference
Element
Attr
ProcessingInstruction
Comment
Text
CDATASection
Entity
Notation
```

What confuses me here are the idea of `Entity` nodes.

I understand what an `Entity` node is - it basically let's you define an "entity" which can later be referenced using the `&;` syntax, and expanded.  It's sort of like a way to use variables in XML.

Okay, but what really confuses me is that, as far as I understand, `!ENTITY` nodes generally can only appear within DTDs (Document Type Definitions.)  But a DTD is really a totally separate format from XML, with totally separate node types, like `!ELEMENT` nodes, `!ATTLIST` nodes and `!ENTITY` nodes.  A DTD can be *embedded* within an XML document using the ubiquitous `!DOCTYPE` declaration, but my question is:

Why are `!ENTITY` nodes *specifically* given a node type in the W3C DOM specification, whereas other DTD node types aren't?  Why don't we see `!ELEMENT` nodes and `!ATTLIST` nodes in the W3C DOM model?  Why are only `!ENTITY` nodes included as a node type?  Can an `!ENTITY` node appear *outside* of a DTD, within an XML document somehow?

Comment: The doc pages for [`Entity`](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Entity.html) and [`EntityReference`](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/EntityReference.html) might offer a hint. I don't claim to understand them fully, but I'm guessing the DOM needs to represent the mapping of references to their corresponding entities.

Answer (score 0):

[`Entity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Entity) and [`EntityReference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EntityReference) interfaces are not used on the web and are not implemented in at least some (if not all) of the web browsers. The DOM specification is not limited to the web though, so these objects can appear in non-browser implementations of the DOM.

The `Entity` objects indeed represent the custom `<!ENTITY ...>` declarations and can be obtained via [`DocumentType::entities`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1788794630). I guess `Entity` is a subclass of `Node` because an entity can expand to a tree of nodes.

`EntityReference`s can appear in the DOM tree in place of the entity reference (`&ent;`). This will only happen if the XML/HTML parser  operates in an *entity-preserving* mode. The parser will also provide an entity expansion in the subtree of the `EntityReference`.

["Reading Entity Declarations and Entity References into the DOM"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btz868zc(v=vs.110).aspx) and the following section, ["Entity References are Preserved"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/echt5wax(v=vs.110).aspx), from the .NET Framework documentation explains this in more detail.

Comment: Do you have any non-Microsoft specific articles?

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure why you ask, since this will always be specific to a particular DOM/XML parser implementation. Apparently xerces also can preserve EntityReferences via the ["http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/create-entity-ref-nodes" feature](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#dom.create-entity-ref-nodes)